# Chart.js: One function for multiple graphs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am using [charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

I have multiple elements that are being pulled from a database. My goal is to attach a graph for each of these elements. However, at times there are 30 elements on a page, so it would be incredibly painful to write scripts for each of these. So I am trying to create a graph for each `#line`...

This works, but only for the first graph (because I am using `.get(0)`:

```
$('#line').each(function(){
    var ctx = $(this).get(0).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data);
});
```

But this does not work:

```
$('#line').each(function(){
    var ctx = $(this).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data);
});
```

How come I cannot use `.getcontext()` without using `.get()`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have multiple identical id's in your html page. Therefore, you cannot cycle through an array of identical id's as you are trying to do here:

```
$('#line').each(function(){
    var ctx = $(this).get(0).getContext("2d");
    new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data);
});
```

You have to use classes instead of id's.

The .get(0) returns the first instance of the element you are searching for with jQuery. You can't get a context without first getting an element. What you need to do is increment that '0' in order to retrieve the other instances.

This can be accomplished by passing the index and element into the function like:

```
$('.line').each(function(index, element)
```

So your code should actually look like this:

```
$('.line').each(function(index, element){          
  var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
  new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data);
});
```

And you'll need to update the canvas elements in your html to use class="line" instead of id="line".

Additionally, if you want to have different data showing on each chart, I recommend creating an array to hold data objects like:

```
var data = [];
```

and then adding data objects to it so they can be accessed by index number as well, like this:

```
$('.line').each(function(index, element){          
  var ctx = element.getContext("2d");
  new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data[index]);
});
```

I'm using this method for three line charts in one page, each with different data, as seen here:

[image]

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps you get your charts set up the way you want them!

Comment: Were you able to build this data list dynamically or did you set each one manually? I am having a lot of pain trying to set multiple graphs based on content that changes on the page constantly.

Comment: The charts I showed here used static data, just as an example of how to use one function for initialization of many charts. I am planning on implementing Chart.js within an Angular.js project, using data binding to keep the charts updated dynamically. My idea is to have my data array ( of chart data objects ) on the $scope of a controller, then set up a polling service to query my data source on a set interval to keep the charts updated. I haven't tried implementing this yet, but that's how I plan on tackling the issue you're describing.

Comment: I get this error when I try have different data on each chart `Attempted to assign to readonly property.`